# Inventor Filleting Issue

Tags: technical-drawing, drafting, drawings, autodesk-inventor

I am a beginner practicing with Inventor 2021 LT and I was working on the following sample drawing when I ran into an issue with fillets:

[image: Example 107]

At the top edge of the U-shape slot, a rounded corner can be seen between the out side edge of the U and the the outside face of the vertical wall.  Since the U shape protrude 3 mm I did not think there would be an issue.  I tried filleting around the outside of the U (not top) and the top and side edge of the vertical wall, but that failed.  I tried different orders of selecting but that did not change anything

[image: All fillets selected]

If I fillet the U first, apply it, then try to fillet the back wall, The edge becomes continuous and fillets out to the face of the U which is not like the example.

[image]

If I fillet the back wall first, apply it, then fillet the U it fails to create the fillet.

[image]

So far this is the closest I can get. which misses the fillet around the U.

[image]

**Is there something special I need to do to make this filleting work?**

Comment: I have not done any testing, but perhaps the fillet will work if you extrude the face of the U further away, fillet the edge, and then cut it back. In real life this fillet is formed on a larger bit of material by casting, and then the face of the U is post machined.

Comment: What do the instructions say about filleting?

Comment: Did you assign the fillet size as "3"? Reduce it to "1" and see how it goes. Note, the fillet on the circle wasn't correct either.